# Line editing with zsh's vared from within script

Tags: zsh

When using macOS 11's stock `/bin/zsh` shell ("*zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin20.0)*"), I can run the following commands from the shell, and I will be prompted with "*somevalue*" pre-filled:

```sh
VARIABLE="somevalue"
vared -p "PROMPT: " VARIABLE
```

As expected, I can edit the "*somevalue*" pre-filled value using standard line-editing keystrokes.

However, if I put those exact commands in a "testinput.zsh" script and run it, I am prompted for "*somevalue*", but it is not editable: keyboard commands do not permit editing the "*somevalue*" value. I can't even hit delete to clear the value and enter my own, thus making it impossible to override the default value passed to `vared` (and thus rendering it useless).

Can this be controlled by some setting? I've found that it *will* work if I add the "-i" flag to the script like so:

```sh
#!/bin/zsh -i
VARIABLE="value"
vared -p "PROMPT: " VARIABLE
```

However, this seems to have side-effects, as seen in the output from the script when run with "-i":

```
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

My question: is there a way to force `vared` into "interactive" mode so that line-editing keybindings work? If not, is there any way to detect when `vared` won't be in interactive mode (e.g., based on some tty setting), so that I can at least avoid adding a pre-filled variable to the user that they won't be able to change?

**Update**: The context is that this is part of a set of scripts distributed with a project, and having users need to mess around with their `.zshrc` or other configuration environment isn't an option. I need to figure out how to identify when a user will have the same issue as I am seeing, and either work-around the limitation or else just identify it in order to prevent `vared` from leaving the user stuck with an un-editable default value for their configuration property.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with zsh, but this might be caused by one shell being interactive and the other rather operating as simple script interpreter.

Comment: Which terminal are you using?

Comment: Terminal.app with, AFAIK, all the default settings in terms of TTY behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you have `EDITOR` set to some flavor of vi.  You can check this by adding `bindkey -Ll main` in your script -- if I'm right, it will print "bindkey -A viins main".  Your variable is editable, but the editor is using vi emulation mode -- specifically, `viins`, so you would need to press ESC before being able to move around and delete existing content.  You can see the same effect interactively by starting a sub-zsh (just type `zsh`) and trying to use `vared` as before.  The relevant bit of documentation is in `zshzle`(1), "KEYMAPS":

> ...either "emacs" or "viins" is also linked to the  name "main".  If one of the VISUAL or EDITOR environment variables contain the string "vi" when the  shell starts up then it will be "viins", otherwise it will be "emacs".

This isn't an issue in your login shell (or, apparently, an interactive one) because `EDITOR` is initially unset, so you get `emacs` unless you specifically override it.  Your command's shell, however, inherits your customized `EDITOR` and selects `viins`.  I can think of a few options:

- Learn to love vi mode in `vared`.
- Override zsh's choice by using `vared -M emacs`.
- Override zsh's choice by invoking your script with `EDITOR` undefined (for example, `EDITOR= ./test.zsh`).  This is slightly different than the previous option because it's using zsh's default behavior rather than specifically selecting `emacs`.

As a side note, because your script is written as an executable, not a function, changes it makes to variables will *not* be visible in the invoking shell.  That may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Works for me. Example:

I created a script `ve` containing the two lines

```
vared XX
echo New value: $XX
```

and invoked it as

```
XX=A zsh ve
```

I could edit XX and got *New value: edited value* printed on stdout.

Comment: Doesn't work for me: same issue. What platform/version of zsh are you running on?

Comment: zsh 5.8 running on Cygwin. In theory it could be an issue of the zsh version, though I would be surprised if it is. Can you post in the comment a screenshot demonstrating that my example does not work on your side? Just do a `cat ve; XX=A zsh ve` and edit the variable, then do the screenshot.